# Tableau JavaScript API filter function in Shiny R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, tableau-api

I'm doing a test to integrate Tableau JavaScript API into an single-page shiny App. I've successfully rendered the Tableau Viz, but filter functions won't work.

Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

useShinyjs(),

tags$head(tags$script(src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js")),
 extendShinyjs(text='shinyjs.initializeViz = function(){
var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
  var url = "http://public.tableau.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita";
  var options = {
  hideTabs: true,
  hideToolbar: true,
  onFirstInteractive: function () {
  workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
  activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
  }
  };
  viz = new tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
  }
shinyjs.filterSingleValue= function(filtername, value){
activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
  filtername,
  value,
  tableau.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
  }  '),

titlePanel("Tableau JavaScript API in Shiny App"),

selectInput('region', 'Region: ', 
  c('The Americas', 'Europe', 'Middle East')), 
 tags$div(id = 'tableauViz')
  ),

 server = function(input, output, session){

    observeEvent(input$region, {
      js$filterSingleValue('Region', input$region)
      js$initializeViz()
    })
  } 
)
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find a way out...
For some reason, when converting JavaScript functions to shinyjs.function, it can only recognize one parameter, i.e. in this case rewrite the filter function by removing the first parameter:

```
shinyjs.filterSingleValue= function(value) {
activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
'Region',
value, 
tableau.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
}
```

This should fix the problems. 
Thanks for anyone who spent your precious time on this...